# ModuleFederationPlugIn giving error caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') when loading host app

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

When I load my host react app, I get this error: caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

here is my web pack config for app1

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: 'app1',
    filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
    exposes: {
        './ReceiptApp': './src/bootstrap.js'
    },
})
```

container app config

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: 'container',
  remotes: {
    receipt: 'app1@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js',
  },
})
```

app1 has a bootstrap.js file that exports a mount function which renders the App component on an element.  it's index.js imports bootstrap.js

The App component of the container app is

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'receipt/ReceiptApp';

console.log(mount);

export default () => {
  return (
    <div>Container</div>
  )
}
```

The container app also has a bootstrap.js file that renders the App component. and it's index.js just imports bootstrap.js

I am not sure why I am getting the error
`moteEntry.js:330 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')     at __webpack_require__ (remoteEntry.js:330:33)     at fn (remoteEntry.js:563:21)     at eval (App.js:7:76)     at ./src/App.js (src_bootstrap_js.js:18:1)     at __webpack_require__ (remoteEntry.js:330:33)     at fn (remoteEntry.js:563:21)     at eval (bootstrap.js:5:62)     at ./src/bootstrap.js (src_bootstrap_js.js:28:1)     at __webpack_require__ (remoteEntry.js:330:33)     at fn (remoteEntry.js:563:21) _`

When the container app loads, I can see it is loading the remoteEntry.js file with app1